# Is there a way to convert coordinate points between different device sizes? (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, coordinate-systems, screen-size

I am following some tutorials online but the code is meant for an iPad. I am working with an iPhone and the screen sizes are different. The problem is that the author uses 'magic numbers' that are made specifically for the iPad.

I have been successful in creating conversions so that it will work for any device. For example:

```
let xMid : CGFloat = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
let yMid : CGFloat = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)
print("x: \(xMid) y: \(yMid)")

let height : CGFloat = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)
let width  : CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth (self.frame)

makeSlotAt(CGPoint(x: xMid / 4.0,              y: 0), isGood: true)
makeSlotAt(CGPoint(x: xMid - xMid / 4.0,       y: 0), isGood: false)
makeSlotAt(CGPoint(x: xMid + xMid / 4.0,       y: 0), isGood: true)
makeSlotAt(CGPoint(x: xMid * 2.0 - xMid / 4.0, y: 0), isGood: false)

makeBouncerAt(CGPoint(x: 0,          y: 0))
makeBouncerAt(CGPoint(x: xMid / 2.0, y: 0))
makeBouncerAt(CGPoint(x: xMid,       y: 0))
makeBouncerAt(CGPoint(x: xMid * 1.5, y: 0))
makeBouncerAt(CGPoint(x: xMid * 2.0, y: 0))
```

Anyway, I was just wondering if there was a function or cheat sheet that had numerical conversions between device sizes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tutorial you're using uses magic numbers, then stop using it immediately. If you use autolayout and follow Apple's guidelines for iOS 7 & up, you rarely, if ever, need to use magic numbers. The functions that you created are a good start for in-code measurements.

Comment: Yeah, these kind of tutorials result in apps that break once the statusbar doubles in size (while tethering or hotspotting, for instance).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't use UIKit tutorials that are more than a couple years old, especially if you're just starting out.

Comment: The tutorials that I'm following are called Hacking with Swift: https://www.hackingwithswift.com

Comment: Swift tutorials?! Those are, by definition, less than two years old, so they shouldn't be using magic numbers! Which particular tutorial is it, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: @NRitH I am talking about Hacking with Swift: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/     Lesson 11: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/11/overview     Lesson 14: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/14/overview